# CakePHP Get IP Address

Tags: php, cakephp, ip-address

How can I get the client's IP address in CakePHP? It'd be `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in plain PHP.

I thought it's like all `$_SERVER` vars and can be accessed using `env('VAR_NAME')`, or `getClientIP()` in CakePHP, but it doesn't return the same results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**CakePHP 1.x**:

[`RequestHandlerComponent::getClientIp();`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.1/en/the-request-handler-component.html)

So to clarify:

```
public $components = array(
    'RequestHandler'
);
```

Then in the controller method:

```
$this->RequestHandler->getClientIp();
```

**CakePHP 2.x & CakepPHP 3.x**:

`RequestHandler::getClientIp()` is deprecated; you can get the client IP from the [`CakeRequest` object](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakerequest):

```
$this->request->clientIp();
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great. I have heard that RequestHandler can be slower than using pure php $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. Is this true?

Comment: Well, adding layers of complexity always slows down processing but this does more than simply: `return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`.

Comment: `getClientIp(false)` might be advisable in certain situations, sometimes (like on Heroku) the IP is in HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR.

Comment: It's deprecated, use `$this->request->clientIp()` from your, controller instead.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for the tip, you probably saved me a lot of pain and misery.

Comment: How can i do it for cake version 3.2

Answer (score 14):

CakePHP 3.x usage:

```
//in controller
$ip = $this->request->clientIp();
```

CakePHP 2.x usage

```
//in controller
$this->request->ClientIp();
```

CakePHP 1.x usage

```
//in controller
RequestHandlerComponent::getClientIP();
```

Comment: If inside a model, do `$ServerRequest = new \Cake\Http\ServerRequest();` and then `$entity->remote_addr = $ServerRequest->clientIp();`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get the IP address from within a model, `$this->request->getClientIp()` won't work, throwing:

> **Error:** Call to a member function clientIp() on a non-object

Use `Router::getRequest()->clientIp()` instead.

So basically, `Router::getRequest()` can serve as a *Model*'s replacement of the *Controller*'s `$this->request`

Answer (score 2):

In cakephp 3.x

In your controller to get the client ip - $this->request->clientIp();

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `$this->request->clientIp();` to get the current visitor's IP address.

```
Cake\Http\ServerRequest::clientIp()
Returns the current visitor’s IP address.
```

For further reference
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#reading-http-headers

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp 3 have clientIP function in the class ServerRequest:

> https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Http/ServerRequest.php#L578

### You can access:

### in a controller controller:

```php
 $this->request->clientIp();
```

### in a controller controller:

```php
 // firts add Router support
 use Cake\Routing\Router;
 // Use in a method
 Router::getRequest()->clientIp()
```

I leave the function if you use a previous version of the framework or require some special behavior:

```php
public function clientIp()
{
    if ($this->trustProxy && $this->getEnv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
        $addresses = explode(',', $this->getEnv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'));
        $ipaddr = end($addresses);
    } elseif ($this->trustProxy && $this->getEnv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')) {
        $ipaddr = $this->getEnv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    } else {
        $ipaddr = $this->getEnv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    }
    return trim($ipaddr);
}
```

For example, this function returns the value ":: 1" when you work in a local environment.

It is a good idea to add it in the bootstrap.php boot file, since you can access it from anywhere:

```php
function clientIp($defaultIP = '127.0.0.1') {
        $ipaddr = null;
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ipaddr = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ipaddr = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {
            $ipaddr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        $ipaddr = trim($ipaddr);
        if ($ipaddr == '::1') {
            $ipaddr = $defaultIP;
        }
        return $ipaddr;
}
```

good luck and happy coding! =D