# Cakephp return host Ip instead of client

Tags: cakephp

I had uploaded my project to my server, and when I was debugging, I realized that the system was returning the host's IP instead the IP of the client. There was not difference if it was done using CakePHP (`$this->request->clientIp`) or by native PHP code. I extracted the snippet from the project and tested it in a single PHP file and there it works fine.

Does someone know how to make CkaePHP return the client IP? I'm using `CakePHP 2.1`

What is rolling is:
 - Cakephp returns host IP, I can use `$this->request->clienteIp();` or plan php with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.
 - Both of them return the Ip of the server where is hosted my project.
 - I tested other project(without cakephp framework) with the method `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and works fine.
 - I need the client, the Ip of the users(using the framework of Cakephp).

Comment: If it's not returning it using the plain PHP way then of course Cake will be wrong, because it uses PHP to [grab the IP](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/cake-request#line-359). Sounds like server misconfiguration to me.

Comment: Do you mean it could be a routing issue?

Comment: No, it likely has nothing to do with routing. If PHP isn't populating it correctly then it's a PHP or web server configuration problem.

Comment: But files outside cakephp return the correct Ip of visitor.

Answer (score 0):

*Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5675320/1110760 as an aswer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5675265/1110760) - If you upvote this, please consider to upvote the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5675320/1110760) as well*

**CakePHP 1.x**:

[`RequestHandlerComponent::getClientIp();`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/request-handler-component#method-RequestHandlerComponentgetClientIP)

So to clarify:

```
public $components = array(
    'RequestHandler'
);
```

Then in the controller method:

```
$this->RequestHandler->getClientIp();
```

**CakePHP 2.x**:

`RequestHandler::getClientIp()` is deprecated; you can get the client IP from the [`CakeRequest` object](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakerequest):

```
$this->request->clientIp();
```

---

So, are you sure you are using the method (`$this->request->clientIp()`) instead of the variable (`$this->request->clientIp`)? Like you mentioned in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cakephp 2.xx

```
$this->request->clientIp();
```

You can use native PHP server variable

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

This is working example of my application on CakePhP

```
function getIp(){
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){    //check ip from share internet
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){   //to check ip is pass from proxy
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            } else {
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            }
return $ip;
}
```

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is working outside cakephp. Inside the framework is returning the Ip of my server.

Comment: So when you dump `$_SERVER` it's wrong? That's odd, I've never seen Cake overwrite environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved on my own.
The debug returned `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']` with the user ip.
When I realized that I found this site:
http://www.maheshchari.com/real-ip-address/

Comment: Sounds like a proxy. Would be nice to open this up on Cake's ticket tracker and supply a patch so other users get the benefit of your debugging :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did it: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/3577-this-request-clientip-is-returning-server-ip