# Add Ip Address into cakephp logs

Tags: php, cakephp

I am currenly checking CakePhp error.log and I find strange requests, like if it was a bot trying to curl some urls.

Is there a way to add the Ip Address at the beginning of the line for each error stored ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675265/cakephp-get-ip-address

Comment: I saw this post but this one is only how to get the ip address. Mine is how to add it everywhere on the error.log when something wrong happens.

Comment: just add it to the log when you are creating it..

Comment: I am not creating the log ($this->log()), I talk about the error.log (like if you call a wrong url, missing controller, ...)

Comment: override the default logger.

Comment: How ... ? Sorry I am not a cakephp expert and I didn't find any answer into google related to my needs...

Comment: Pretty much every web server will have access logs that contain the ip address already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this code to the `AppController` -

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->log("Request from - ".$this->request->clientIp(), 'error');
}
```

this will log the ip of client to error log file before any filtering.

Comment: 2014-09-17 04:55:03 Warning: Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to AppController::beforeFilter() must be an instance of Event, instance of CakeEvent given in [/home/wmediain/public_html/missilepronos.com/app/Controller/AppController.php, line 42]

Comment: Also, I have already this function in beforeFilter() : $this->_setErrorLayout(); ... Do I need to add a condition for $this->log ?

Comment: updated my answer. that was for `cakephp 3`. you can code as what you need. if needed any condition then add it.

Comment: Thanks for update. I need to log only on errors ('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'), how can I pass this parameter to the beforeFilter in order to add the condition ?

Comment: plz sometimes go through the `docs` also. you should understand how these works.

Comment: I do it many times a day :) Btw I can understand, thanks for help.